# Can't change opacity of image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, opacity

I'm trying to get a image to change opacity based on a boolean flag. It should drop opacity when the `var pauseDisabled = true` and go back to a value of `1` when `pauseDisabled = false`.

I created the fiddle below to simulate what I'm attempting. In this example I simply am trying to use a link to control the on/off switch. It won't drop opacity however and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/w51Lxvjp/8/

```
<div class="pause">
    <a class="pause-btn">
        <img class="pause-img" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/buttons/512/Icon_4-512.png">
    </a>
</div>

<a class="disabler" href="#">Disable Button</a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pauseDisabled = false;

    $('.disabler').click(function() {
        pauseDisabled = true;
    })

    if (pauseDisabled === true) {
        $('.pause').css('opacity', '0.2');
    } else if (pauseDisabled === false) {
        $('.pause').css('opacity', '1');
    }
});
```

Comment: You have to put the if statement in the click function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is flawed as the `if` condition will only run once on load of the page. Instead you need to set the opacity each time the `pauseDisabled` flag is toggled within the `click` event handler. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let pauseDisabled = false;

  $('.disabler').click(() => {
    pauseDisabled = !pauseDisabled;
    $('.pause').css('opacity', pauseDisabled ? '0.2' : '1');
  })
});
```

```css
img { width: 250px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pause">
  <a class="pause-btn">
    <img class="pause-img" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/buttons/512/Icon_4-512.png">
  </a>
</div>
<a class="disabler" href="#">Disable Button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to create this if else outside of this click event . You can change the opacity directly inside the click event .

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
  var pauseDisabled = false;

  $('.disabler').click(function() {

     if (pauseDisabled === false) {
    $('.pause').css('opacity', '0.2');
    pauseDisabled = true;
  } else if (pauseDisabled === true) {
    $('.pause').css('opacity', '1');
    pauseDisabled = false;
  }
  })


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jsFiddle has been updated:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/w51Lxvjp/15/
```

Essentially, your IF structure was executed only once, before any click on the link.

```
$('.disabler').click(function() {
    pauseDisabled = !pauseDisabled;
    if (pauseDisabled === true) {
    $('.pause-img').css('opacity', '0.2');
  } else {
    $('.pause-img').css('opacity', '1');
  }
})
```